# Safari heats up iPhone with iOS 11

Tags: html, ios, performance, mobile-safari

I found a strange behavior of Safari on iOS 11.
If I open [any page](https://vc.ru/30535-delimobil-predlozhil-klientam-peregnat-mashiny-iz-moskvy-v-sankt-peterburg-za-schet-kompanii) of [our website](https://vc.ru) on the same devices (tested for iPhones 5 and 6) but with different iOS versions: 10 and 11, then device with iOS 11 starts to heat up.
Using Safari timeline I found out that iOS 11 *(pic.1)*, unlike iOS 10 *(pic.2)*, produces many layout rendering events.
It's strange, considering that there's **was no any user actions while the timeline was being recorded**.
What could be reason for such behavior?

[image: Pic.1: iOS 11]*Pic.1: iOS 11*
[image: Pic.2: iOS 10]*Pic.2: iOS 10*